# TexStudio autocompletion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

How can I make TexStudio autocomplete the commands in gb4e such as \begin{exe}?
It doesn't suggest \begin{exe} automatically and doesn't autocomplete \end{exe}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [TeXStudio FAQ: Why does a comman not show up in the completion?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion)

Answer (score 0):

You should look under Options->Configure TeXStudio->Completion and check the packages you want TeXStudio to search through when autocompleting commands.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find gb4e in the list.

Comment: @mangotango That might mean that the autocompletion file is not available for this package. You can, however, create your own, as documented [in the TeXStudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is somewhat old, but I found myself in a similar situation yesterday and I think I have found a solution that might help others.

When I opened TexStudio today, some commands that did not autocomplete yesterday were working fine, but others were not. Also, I clearly remember that all commands autocompleted before.

So, here is what I figured out today. If you put all your commands in a separate file like me, TexStudio will detect them for the autocompletion unless those files are opened at least once. I found that everything was working fine after I opened all my command and packages files. I could close them afterwards and everything still works. If I close the TexStudio app, then I have to reopen the files otherwise the autocomplete does not work properly.

Hope this helps others !

Note that I use TexStudio on MacOS Sierra. I can't say if this makes a difference.